# Ping subnet but skip some IPs in range with bash

Tags: bash, loops

I have a simple for loop which uses ssh to get hostname on a subnet.  Is it possible to have it skip a certain number of IPs in the same loop?  Here's what I use:

```
for i in 192.168.138.{1..254}; do ssh $i "hostname -s";done
```

I'd like to skip 192.168.138.80 through 100.  I've tried the following with no luck.

```
for i in 192.168.138.{1..79..101..254}; do ssh $i "hostname -s";done
```

or

```
for i in 192.168.138.{1..79}{101..254}; do ssh $i "hostname -s";done
```

I there any way to do this in a one liner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curly brace syntax (sequence expression) can be nested like so:

```
for i in {{1..79},{101..254}}; do ssh 192.168.138."$i" "hostname -s"; done
```